# Rust macro split expression into bytes and into byte vector

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I am having issues getting this functionality to work.

I basically need a macro that will accept a vector of bytes and an expression to be inserted into the vector.

#### Example

```rust
let mut bytes: Vec<u8> = vec![0x0; 6];
println!("{:?}", bytes);

let a: u32 = 0xf1f2f3f4;

convert!(bytes, &a);
println!("{:?}", bytes);
```

#### Output:

```
[0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0]
[0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0x0, 0x0]
```

This definitely feels like something that should exist (like sending over wire). I can't however find anything in the documentation. And if there isn't; I could need some help getting there or linked relevant resources (already know about DanielKeep's [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book)) that could help me.

Comment: Why a macro specifically? Why not a function?

Comment: I'd prefer it to be a macro to keep my code clean. This functionality is used by a second macro for initialising stuff with a variable number of arguments.

Edit: this will be one macro if I get it to work.

Comment: Prefer functions wherever you can, use macros only when you must. Macros won't keep your code clean; they'll do the opposite.

Comment: This is an optional helper macro. Got tired of specifying and hard-coding configurations manually so made this macro for just that.
```rust
set_field!(&mut f;
    0, 0, 2;
    1, 0, 4;
    2, 0, 7;
);
```

Comment: Your macro can call functions, so I still don't get why it should be a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want a macro, this can be done very simply with a function:

```rust
fn assign_u32(bytes: &mut [u8], v: u32) {
    bytes[..4].copy_from_slice(&v.to_be_bytes());
}
```

And using it like:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut bytes: Vec<u8> = vec![0x0; 6];
    println!("{:x?}", bytes);

    let a: u32 = 0xf1f2f3f4;

    assign_u32(&mut bytes, a);
    println!("{:x?}", bytes);
}
```